# For loop stops adding items and values to a dictionary after first iteration

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to split the word in half and calculate the occurrence of each letter in the word and insert the score in dictionary the output should be like this:

`word`: aaazzbbb

`dict1`: first half of the word

```
{'a': 3,'z': 1}
```

The issue is that the adding stops

`dict2`: the second half

```
{'b': 3,'z': 1}
```

As it seems to stop adding items to the dictionary after the first iteration with the `for` loop which is very strange.

Below is my function and what it gives:

```
def pal2(word):
    wordLength = len(word)
    word1 = ""
    word2 = ""
    midstr = ""
    dict1 = []
    dict2 = []
    if (wordLength % 2 == 0 ):
        for i in range(int((len(word)/2)-1),-1,-1):
            word1 += word[i]
            if (word[i] not in dict1):
                dict1 = {word[i]:word.count(word[i],0,int((len(word)/2)-1))}

        for j in range(int((len(word)/2)),len(word),+1):
            word2 += word[j]
            if (word[j] not in dict2):
                dict2 = {word[j]:word.count(word[j],int((len(word) / 2) - 1), len(word))}
```

This is what it gives:

```
{'a': 3}, {'b': 3}
```

As you can see only the first letters are inserted.

Comment: You're reassigning `dict2` to a brand new dictionary every time through the loop, which discards the value from the previous loop.

Comment: In your own words, when `dict1 = {word[i]:word.count(word[i],0,int((len(word)/2)-1))}` happens, what do you expect to happen to the previous contents of `dict1`? What do you want this line of code, specifically, to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many problems with your code, I have fixed some of them to make it work:

1. You initialize `dict1` and `dict2` like `lists`, not `dicts`.
2. On each `for` loop iteration you fully override your dict, so you have only one key in the result.

```
dict1 = {word[i]:word.count(word[i],0,int((len(word)/2)-1))}
```

3. You use incorrect indexes in `count` function. You have to use

```
word.count(word[i], 0, int((len(word) / 2)))
```

instead of

```
word.count(word[i],0,int((len(word)/2)-1))
```

and

```
word.count(word[j], int((len(word) / 2)), len(word))
```

instead of

```
word.count(word[j],int((len(word) / 2) - 1), len(word))
```

4. Variable in function should be lowercase, so I replaced `wordLength` with `word_length`. You have to stick to those standards to increase code readability.
5. Fixed some other code style issues.

```
def pal2(word):
    word_length = len(word)
    word1 = ""
    word2 = ""
    dict1 = {}
    dict2 = {}
    if word_length % 2 == 0:
        for i in range(int((len(word) / 2) - 1), -1, -1):
            word1 += word[i]
            if word[i] not in dict1:
                dict1[word[i]] = word.count(word[i], 0, int((len(word) / 2)))
        for j in range(int((len(word) / 2)), len(word), 1):
            word2 += word[j]
            if word[j] not in dict2:
                dict2[word[j]] = word.count(word[j], int((len(word) / 2)), len(word))
    print(dict1)
    print(dict2)


pal2("aaazzbbb")
```

Output:

```
{'z': 1, 'a': 3}
{'z': 1, 'b': 3}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i didn"t know i had this much of problems , i really appreaciate you showing me the good practice as well, and im truly having fun with python now

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a dictionary each time, you need to update your initial dictionary.

To explain, first you have to create an empty dictionary:

```
dict1 = {}
```

Then, we replace this code, where you are creating a completely new dictionary:

```
dict1 = {word[i]:word.count(word[i],0,int((len(word)/2)-1))}
```

By this (update original dictionary, to include existing elements):

```
dict1.update({word[i]:word.count(word[i],0,int((len(word)/2)))})
```

Check the [update](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/update.html)
method.

Comment: Seems unnecessary to create a dictionary containing just one key only to use it to update another dictionary. You can instead just set the value using `dict1[word[i]] = ...`